# Extracting relationship status from Facebook in Python running on Google App Engine

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a Facebook application. It's written in Python and running on Google App Engine (GAE).

I know how to get the relationship status of the users network, but the way I do it is running way to slow. There is a time limit on GAE in order to reduce CPU usage which is about 60 seconds. Using the following code I can get the relationship status of about 200 persons in that time frame, before getting the "DeadlineExceededError". Of course that is not good enough, since many/most people have a higher amount of friends on Facebook.

What I do now, is to get the friend list of the user, and then making an API call for each one asking for the name and relationship status.

**The code I use:**

```
for f in friends:
    friends_info[f] = facebook.api('/'+f, {u'fields': 'name,relationship_status', 
    u'access_token': facebook.access_token})
```

And then I get the data with:

```
rel_status = friends_info[f][u'relationship_status']
```

**What I need:**

Suggestions for optimization or other ways to extract the relationship status of an entire network.

Thanks in advance :-)

**EDIT :**

The answers seems to be all good ways to solve my problem. Though, I couldn't find any good tutorials for batch request in Python, so I ended up using a FQL call. By using the following it takes 1-2 seconds to get the data:

```
Q = 'select uid, sex, relationship_status from user where uid in (select target_id from connection where source_id = me())'
```

And the actual data is retrieved by:

```
data = fql.query(Q,facebook.access_token)
```

which call this function:

```
def query(self,Q,access_token):
    ENDPOINT = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/'
    params = dict(query=Q, access_token=access_token, format='json')
    url = ENDPOINT + 'fql.query'
    return self._fetch(url, params=params)

def _fetch(self, url, params=None):
    conn = urllib2.urlopen(url, data=urlencode(params))
    try:
        return json.loads(conn.read())
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Hope someone can make use of it as well!

Comment: In addition to the two answers below, you should run your code in a Task Queue task, which has a limit of 10 minutes, not 60 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Each app engine instance can have have max 10 parallel HTTP queries, so you could potentially make this 10 times faster with create_rpc & make_fetch_call. There are scenarios where this doesn't work either, so you need to split the job to several tasks and let them run in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the facebook graph [batch query API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to query up to 20 users at once